# How to Display Json Data when ajax request is success

Tags: ajax

Here I am using Ajax+Mvc when I call my data from database it comes in Json format but how can I display that data in div?

**Html**

```
<div id="Div1">
    </div>
    <b>Get data</b><input type="button" id="BtnGetData" value="GetData" />
```

When user click on `BtnGetData` the data should be display in **#Div1**  Here my AJax working fine.
But please suggest me where to write `$('#Div1').load()`;

```
   $('#BtnGetData').click(function () {
              alert('ok data')
                      $.ajax({
                          url: '/Home/Getdata',
                        method: "GET",
                        type: "JSON",
                        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                        data: JSON.stringify(),                  
                    })
                })
```

**MvcController**

```
public JsonResult Getdata()
        {
            var x = Objrepo.GetEmplo();
            return new JsonResult { Data = x, JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet };
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write to the div on the success function of your $.ajax call.

eg:

```
$('#BtnGetData').click(function () {
  $.ajax({
        url: '/Home/Getdata',
        method: "GET",
        type: "JSON",
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        data: JSON.stringify(),       
        success: function (data) {        
            console.log(data);
        }       
    })
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a success callback to your ajax:

```
 $('#BtnGetData').click(function () {
              alert('ok data')
                      $.ajax({
                        url: '/Home/Getdata',
                        method: "GET",
                        type: "JSON",
                        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                        success: function(data){
                             $("#Div1").append(data);
                         }
                    })
                })
```

There is no need to add the data property to the ajax if your are not sending anything.

Answer (score 0):

May be, you can add this function in your script.

```
      $('#BtnGetData').click(function () {
                  alert('ok data')
                          $.ajax({
                              url: '/Home/Getdata',
                            method: "GET",
                            type: "JSON",
                            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                            data: JSON.stringify(), 
                            writeResponse(data)                 
                        })
                    });
        writeResponse(data){
       $("Div1").html(data);
};
```